# Alertdialog.Builder's setItems() onClick returning null dialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am making a custom Alertdialog.Builder and took the liberty of extending the work done by danoz73, found here https://github.com/danoz73/QustomDialog.

I have implemented my own `setItems()` method in the class `QustomDialogBuilder.java` (a subclass of AlertDialog.Builder). Since the items I pass are not the standard, the method is **NOT** marked as `Override`.

```
    public QustomDialogBuilder setItems(ArrayList<KMColor> items, final DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {
    LinearLayout itemList = (LinearLayout) mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.items_list);//INFLATE THE LINEARLAYOUT INSIDE THE SCROLLVIEW
    Log.i("TAG","1 setItems items dialog is "+mDialog);//<--THIS IS NULL

    //HIDE UNUSED VIEWS SO THERE ISN'T A SPACE
    mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.customPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.contentPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE);

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        KMColor item = items.get(i);

        View listItem = inflateItem(item.name,item.color);
        listItem.setId(item.color);//VIEWS IDS CAN'T BE 0
        itemList.addView(listItem);
        Log.i("TAG","2 setItems items dialog is "+mDialog);//<--THIS IS NULL

        if (listener != null) {
            /*itemList <-- doesn't tell you what item was clicked*/
            listItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i("TAG","3 setItems items dialog is "+mDialog);//<--STILL NULL 
                    listener.onClick(mDialog, v.getId());
                }
            });
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

[image: Custom Dialog with setItems()]

This all works fine I get the custom dialog I want to display. BUT when I select an item I get the id however my dialog retuned from the onClick is null so I cannot dismiss the dialog!

```
        alert.setItems(items,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.i("TAG", "setItems dialog is " + dialog);//<--null, so I crash if I try to dismiss()

        }
    });
```

Back in `QustomDialogBuilder.java` here is the show override I use to grab the dialog.

```
    @Override
public AlertDialog show() {
    if (mTitle.getText().equals("")) mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.topPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (mMessage.getText().equals("")) mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.contentPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mDialog = super.show();//<--GET THE DIALOG TO PASS IN THE ONCLICK

    Log.i("TAG","AlertDialog show()  dialog is "+ mDialog);
    return mDialog;
}
```

I'm sure I could grab reference to the dialog in a different manner however I'd really like to understand why this isn't quit working the way I expect it to. I would appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

**EDIT** Here is how I build the dialog

```
public void showColorPicker(){

    QustomDialogBuilder alert = new QustomDialogBuilder(context);
    alert.setTitle("Pick Color");
    alert.setTitleColorWithResource(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    alert.setDividerColorWithResource(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));


    ArrayList<KMColor> items = new ArrayList<KMColor>();
    items.add(new KMColor("Black",Color.BLACK));
    items.add(new KMColor("Blue",Color.BLUE));
    items.add(new KMColor("Cyan",Color.CYAN));
    items.add(new KMColor("Green",Color.GREEN));
    items.add(new KMColor("Dark Grey",Color.DKGRAY));
    items.add(new KMColor("Light Grey",Color.LTGRAY));
    items.add(new KMColor("Magenta",Color.MAGENTA));
    items.add(new KMColor("Red",Color.RED));
    items.add(new KMColor("White",Color.WHITE));
    items.add(new KMColor("Yellow",Color.YELLOW));

    alert.setItems(items,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.i("TAG", "setItems dialog is " + dialog);//<--NULL

        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            // if this button is clicked, just close
            // the dialog box and do nothing
            dialog.cancel();//<--WORKS FINE
        }
    });
    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: go to super.show(); and check when it returns null

Comment: Actually the `show()` doesn't appear to ever get called?

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassed to say I found the answer. My problem was here

```
 // create alert dialog
AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
// show it
alertDialog.show();
```

I was calling `create()` on my Alertdialog.Builder however I was not `Override`ing the `create()` in `QustomDialogBuilder.java`, I was only `Override`ing the `show()` therefore I never got a handle on the dialog! simple fix! The above code is now just

```
alert.show();
```

I now also `Override` the `create()` in `QustomDialogBuilder.java`. Same thing as the `show()` but now I won't accidentally chase my tail!

```
    @Override
public AlertDialog create() {
    if (mTitle.getText().equals("")) mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.topPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (mMessage.getText().equals("")) mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.contentPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mDialog = super.create();
    return mDialog;
}
```